# Express API request through Nginx not working

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy, pm2

I have a full-stack app (Vue for the front end and Node.js for the back end) that is running on an AWS EC2 instance.

For running frontend, I build the Vue app by using `npm run build` and then copy the built `dist` folder to `/var/www/html`.

And for the backend, I use [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

to keep running the Node.js service in the background.

And also I installed nginx to serve both frontend and backend. Here's the nginx config.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                root /var/www/html;
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location /v1 {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:6200/v1;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header content-type "application/json";
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        }
}
```

The reverse proxy for the backend should pass to `http://localhost:6200/v1`. It has `v1` which is used by prefix in the Node.js backend.

```
app.use('/v1', apiRouter)
```

The front end and back end work fine. I can realize that by using `pm2 log` and nginx logs.

What I am going to do is to use the reverse proxy server as the backend directly.

I have an API request like this on my front end.

```
axios.get('http://localhost/v1/test')
```

The front end fails to request that API. I can request the API using a domain like `https://mytestdomain.com/v1/test`, but I need to request the API on the local instance directly because it would be very faster and avoid some issues.

I am not sure what I did wrong. I tried to update the url like `127.0.0.1` not `localhost` and also using trailing slashes like `/v1/ => proxy_pass http://localhost:6200/v1/`, but they didn't work as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try it with trailing slashes:

```
...
location /v1/ { 
  proxy_pass http://localhost:6200/v1/;
...
```

Update after comment...

Try it with this common server block:

```
  location /v1/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:6200/v1/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header x-real-ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header Referer           $http_referer;
  }
```

Comment: Please see my question again. Basically, I already tried and it didn't work as well.

Comment: See the updated answer. Is content-type "application/json" necessary?

Comment: I removed the content type and also updated the nginx config as well as the API endpoint as `http://127.0.0.1/v1/test`, but it didn't work. The API request says `failed net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.